# JS open new window with text-only mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I want to open an URL in a new window without images(text-only mode). Is there a way to programmatically disable the loading of images(or overall network usage of tab)?

I'm currently working on a personal google chrome extension, where I'm loading a webpage in new window just for source code extraction(which is dynamically loaded so fetch and ajax won't work), if there is a better alternative then please do share.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe u could somehow work with `view-source:https://example.com` ?

Comment: A server side headless browser like puppeteer or selenium might be an alternative but your use case needs more specific details for anyone to properly asses your needs. As it stands currently this question is far too vague. See [ask]

Comment: Use chrome.webRequest to redirect all requests for this tab id with type `image` to a dummy URL like `data:,`

Comment: @johnSmith can't do that. the content I'm looking for is loaded by javascript. view-source only provides static code.